# How to design stateful actors in pure FP way

Tags: scala, akka

I have a task: on message "userStart" start timer for 5 seconds, if user will send answer before timer -> cancel timer. Code is simple and it works, questin is how to make it in FP way. As I understand it, I should use 'val' instead of 'var'. I'm new in FP so I would be glad if some one could help me with this, or recommend some sources where I can find simple samples how to do such things. Thanks!

```
class Game extends Actor{

  var actsCount:Int = 0
  var timer:Option[Cancellable] = None

  def startTimer(): Unit = {
    timer = Some(context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 seconds, self, "userMissed"))
  }

  def receive = {
    case "userStart" => startTimer()
      sender() ! "do move"
    case "userAct" =>
      println("> user made his move")
      actsCount += 1
      if(timer.isDefined)
        timer.get.cancel()
    case "userMissed" => println("> user missed his move")
  }
}
```

Comment: Actors are about having some state (if there is no state, you can replace it with function call). What you can do is to replace var with `context.become`, you can read about it [here (5.2)](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/5-actors.md). But I don't think that in your case (only 2 vars) it's really necessary.

Comment: You can have mutable fields inside actor since it cannot be accessed from outside.

Comment: actors are stateful by nature, so it's generally ok to have a state represented as a mutable value. Apart from `val` vs `var`, the other main thing which is non-FP in your example is the signature of `receive`, which is the infamous `Any => Unit`. If you want to stay in akka world, I can suggest taking a look at Akka-Typed. Other options (for this use case) include using IO from ZIO/Cats or Task from Monix. This blog post is an excellent reference https://blog.softwaremill.com/scalaz-8-io-vs-akka-typed-actors-vs-monix-part-1-5672657169e1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments: your particular use-case is inherently state-full and already encapsulated within an `Actor` which allows for some freedom away from a purely functional paradigm.

However, if you're still not satisfied with your design there are a few options:

**Finite State Machines**

Akka provides mechanisms to allow Actors to behave like FSMs.  In fact, [the example in the documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/fsm.html#a-simple-example) looks very much like your Actor.

**Become/Unbecome**

Actors also have the capability to [change their `receive` method](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/actors.html#become-unbecome) based on messages coming in.  You're timing logic could be embedded in the become & unbecome logic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version using `become` to track the state within the receive function:

```
class Game extends Actor{     
  def startTimer(): Cancellable = context.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(5 seconds, self, "userMissed")

  def receive = idleReceive(0)

  def idleReceive(actsCount: Int): Actor.Receive = {
    case "userStart" => startTimer()
      context.become(waitingReceive(actsCount, startTimer()))
      sender() ! "do move"
  }

  def waitingReceive(actsCount: Int, timer: Cancellable): Actor.Receive = {
    case "userAct" =>
      println("> user made his move")
      context.become(idleReceive(actsCount + 1))
      timer.cancel()
    case "userMissed" =>
      println("> user missed his move")
      context.become(idleReceive(actsCount))
  }
}
```

More error handling is required, including the race condition where the timer fires while the "userAct" message is in transit. You also need to add another message to retrieve the value of `actsCount`.